# what does a[0] = addr & 0xff?

Tags: c, arrays, bit-manipulation

i'm currently learning from the book "the shellcoder's handbook", I have a strong understanding of c but recently I came across a piece of code that I can't grasp.

Here is the piece of code:

```
          char a[4];
          unsigned int addr = 0x0806d3b0;
          a[0] = addr & 0xff;
          a[1] = (addr & 0xff00) >> 8; 
          a[2] = (addr & 0xff0000) >> 16;
          a[3] = (addr) >> 24;
```

So the question is what does this, what is addr & 0xff (and the three lines below it) and what makes >> 8 to it (I know that it divides it 8 times by 2)?
Ps: don't hesitate to tell me if you have ideas for the tags that I should use.

Comment: `(addr) >> X` isn't a divide by `8`. That may be true in some cases, but `>>` is a *right-shift* of `addr` by the number of *bytes* given by `X`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The variable `addr` is 32 bits of data, while each element in the array `a` is 8 bits. What the code does is copy the 32 bits of `addr` into the array `a`, one byte at a time.

Lets take this line:

```
a[1] = (addr & 0xff00) >> 8;
```

And then do it step by step.

1. `addr & 0xff00` This gets the bits 8 to 15 of the value in `addr`, the result after the operation is `0x0000d300`.
2. `>> 8` This shifts the bits to the right, so `0x0000d300` becomes `0x000000d3`.
3. Assign the resulting value of the mask and shift to `a[1]`.

Comment: Is the masking actually *required* here? Would the implicit cast to `char` not take care of that? (BTW I'd also recommend an explicit `unsigned char a[4]`.)

Comment: @Jongware Yes doing it implicitly would work as well. And yes using `unsigned char` (or `uint8_t` to be more specific) would be a good idea.

Comment: In practice you can get away without the masking if you assume a `char` is 8 bits wide. (The C standard says it needs to be _at least_ 8 bits wide.) The masking makes the code portable to platforms where a `char` is wider than 8 bits. And yes, `unsigned char` is better.

Comment: okay I see but how do we know which part of the address is going into our a[1] for example without the mask ?

Answer (score 3):

The code is trying to enforce endianness on the data input. Specifically, it is trying to enforce little endian behavior on the data. Here is the explaination:

```
a[0] = addr & 0xff; /* gets the LSB 0xb0 */
a[1] = (addr & 0xff00) >> 8; /* gets the 2nd LSB 0xd3 */
a[2] = (addr & 0xff0000) >> 16; /* gets 2nd MSB 0x06 */
a[3] = (addr) >> 24; /* gets the MSB 0x08 */
```

So basically, the code is masking and separating out every byte of data and storing it in the array "a" in the little endian format.

Answer (score 2):

```
unsigned char a[4]; /* I think using unsigned char is better in this case */
unsigned int addr = 0x0806d3b0;
a[0] = addr & 0xff; /* get the least significant byte 0xb0 */
a[1] = (addr & 0xff00) >> 8; /* get the second least significant byte 0xd3 */
a[2] = (addr & 0xff0000) >> 16; /* get the second most significant byte 0x06 */
a[3] = (addr) >> 24; /* get the most significant byte 0x08 */
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the code isolates the individual bytes from `addr` to store them in the array `a` so they can be indexed. The first line

```
a[0] = addr & 0xff;
```

masks out the byte of lowest value by using `0xff` as a bit mask; the subsequent lines do the same, but in addition shift the result to the rightmost position. Finally, the the last line

```
a[3] = (addr) >> 24;
```

no masking is necessary anymore, as all unneccesary information is discarded by the shift.

Answer (score 1):

The code is effectively storing a 32 bit adress in a 4 chars long array. As you may know, a char has a byte (8 bit). It first copies the first byte of the adress, then shifts, copies the second byte, then shifts, etc. You get the gist.

Answer (score 1):

It enforces [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), and stores the integer in little-endian format in `a`.

See the [illustration](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ed/Little-Endian.svg) on wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

also, why not visualize the bit shifting results..

```
    char a[4];
    unsigned int addr = 0x0806d3b0;
    a[0] = addr & 0xff;
    a[1] = (addr & 0xff00) >> 8; 
    a[2] = (addr & 0xff0000) >> 16;
    a[3] = (addr) >> 24;

    int i = 0;
    for( ; i < 4; i++ )
    {
        printf( "a[%d] = %02x\t", i, (unsigned char)a[i] );
    }
    printf("\n" );
```

---

Output:

```
a[0] = b0   a[1] = d3   a[2] = 06   a[3] = 08
```

Answer (score 1):

I addition to the multiple answers given, the code has some flaws that need to be fixed to make the code portable. In particular, the `char` type is very dangerous to use for storing values, because of its implementation-defined signedness. Very classic C bug. If the code was taken from a book, then you should read that book sceptically.

While we are at it, we can also tidy up the code, make it overly explicit to avoid potential future maintenance bugs, remove some implicit type promotions of integer literals etc.

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint8_t a[4];
uint32_t addr = 0x0806d3b0UL;
a[0] = addr & 0xFFu;
a[1] = (addr >>  8) & 0xFFu;
a[2] = (addr >> 16) & 0xFFu;
a[3] = (addr >> 24) & 0xFFu;
```

The masks `& 0xFFu` are strictly speaking not needed, but they might save you from some false positive compiler warnings about wrong integer types. Alternatively, each shift result could be cast to `uint8_t` and that would have been fine too.

Comment: thanks a lot for fixing my code, but there are some things that I don't understand ( I don't like to not understand something ) , what does the 0xFFu mask and how is it possible that you remove the old masks? I ask because you are clearly really good at c programming and i'm really eager to learn more about c and especially this kind of stuff .

Comment: @Th3Meg4ph0re The old masks were of type `int` which doesn't make any sense. The difference is that they masked against an `int` before shifting. Now suppose `addr` was also an `int, you would get a right shift on a signed type. If there happened to be any bit in the position of the sign bit, your code would potentially go havoc, since right shifts on negative numbers are not well-defined in C. You could get either an arithmetic or a logical shift, or possibly something else. The `u` or `U` suffix after an integer literal ensures it is of unsigned type.

Comment: @Th3Meg4ph0re As for masking before or after the shift, it doesn't really matter, as long as both operands are unsigned. On small CPUs such as 8 and 16 bit, masking after is more efficient, since it can be done with a 8 bit instruction instead of a 32 bit one. More importantly, masking afterwards make the code look much more tidy. You could even write the first line as `a[0] = (addr >>  0) & 0xFFu;` if you want it to line up more neatly, it will yield equivalent machine code.

Comment: okay thanks for the answer, you made it very clear, however I was wondering, how is it possible that you don't need to specify which part of the address you want to mask for example you shift 0xff00 into just 0xFFu. Why don't you need to specify?

Comment: @Th3Meg4ph0re Because the shift already made sure that the part you are interested in is now in the least significant byte.

Comment: yeah right I forgot that we changed the place of the mask with the shift, thanks a lot for these explanations though I have still one last question : you said that I should read skeptically my book, so I was wondering do you know any book about what we just talked above (uint32_t, uint8_t, unsigned mask, ...) more advanced stuff  than just the basics (pointer, array, int, char, loop, if... ) ? Because i'm eager to learn but I don't know which book I should choose depending on my level.

Comment: @Th3Meg4ph0re I haven't read any C books in ages, the only advise I have there is to get a book which covers at least the C99 standard. Avoid old books, in particular K&R. Avoid internet tutorials, most of them are crap. I would however recommend reading the whole [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/).

Comment: Okay again thanks a lot for all you taught me on this, it was really instructive I really appreciate the time you spent for me